# Comparing the data from a database with the item selected on spinner- Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I've tried the following method to do the task but it isn't working but doesn't show any errors at all.
This is the comparing part:

```
Cursor res = myDb.showKharcha();
final String selected= parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
while(res.moveToNext()) {
    if(selected == res.getString(1)) {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
        num = num + Integer.parseInt(res.getString(2));
        boolean isUpdated = myDb.updateData(res.getString(0),selected,num);
        if (isUpdated == true) {
            Toast.makeText(add_trans.this,"Kharcha updated to "+ selected,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(add_trans.this, "Kharcha not added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

This is the `showKharcha` function in DatabaseHelper class:

```
public Cursor showKharcha(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor tyt = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME,null);
    return tyt;
}
```

The database Update code is:

```
public boolean updateData(String ID, String KharchaType, Integer Kharcha){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(COL_1,ID);
    contentValues.put(COL_2,KharchaType);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,Kharcha);
    db.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues, "ID = ?",new String[] { ID });
    return true;

}
```

Comment: State in the question what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `final String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();` to get selected item from `Spinner`

And

- Try `if(selected.equals(res.getString(1)))` for comparison

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java) for more details about `==` and `equals`

Comment: Thanks this helped but there's another problem now. When the item from spinner matches with the data from database, i need to add `num`  to the data already present in the row and store the sum but it isn't doing so.

Comment: you should write database update code in `myDb.updateData(res.getString(0),selected,num);` method

Comment: Nice played, @ELITE.

Comment: How come your edit uses the same String variable "text" as I did when Ishan had used "selected"?

Comment: `parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();` also does the same, but i'm not 100% sure...

Answer (score 0):

You have talked about comparing the value of the **selected value** from the Spinner.
Use this `final String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();`

instead of

`final String selected= parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();`.

It'd be better if you set an OnItemSelectedListener so that when the user selects, the comparison automatically happens:

```
parent.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
final String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
...rest of the code fro comparison...
}
});
```

Comment: i hadn't used `final` before executing the program but it showed error saying that local variable selected is accessed from within inner class and needs to be declared final.

Comment: Then add final and check. I will update my answer accordingly.